# How do I include a $() element inside a .load();?

Tags: javascript, php, syntax

I'm trying to print some PHP content inside a simple Javascript call. 
The first one I got, but I have 2 vars to include, and one of them, must to be inside a .load().

I'll put the code bellow for a better understanding:

```
<?php

$loadclass = 'filtersin';
$load_address = 'recebimento-filter';
$modal_ID = 'FilterModal';

?>
```

The JS calling (and what I'm trying to do):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var loadclass="<?php echo '.', $loadclass; ?>";
    var load_address="<?php echo $load_address, '.php' ?>";
     $(loadclass).load("dialogs/filter_group/",$(load_address) );

});
</script>
```

Comment: you can only load html files.

Comment: The problem is with the second var (load_address). The first one works fine, but, I have to put $load_address inside the .load(stuff + $load_address).

Comment: I can load php files :) If I type a static address such as .load (mylink.php) works, but the "mylink.php" have an $call. And I have to undertand the Javascript syntax to put this $call inside the .load(blablabla).

Comment: yes the second try to load a `.php` file, but this function can only `.html`files and content. your `$loadadress.php` have to be an `$loadress.html`

Comment: hm ok if you can load this, it is my fault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
 $(loadclass).load("dialogs/filter_group/",$(load_address) );
```

To

```
 $('.' + loadclass).load("dialogs/filter_group/" + load_address );
```

- `loadclass` is now a class. Notice the `.`
- Appended `load_address` properly

#### Please note.

> Description: Load data from the server and place the returned HTML into the matched element.

So, if `dialogs/filter_group/recebimento-filter` does not return HTML it won't work as expected.

To fix this you can add a rewrite rule to `.htaccess`

Comment: Awesome. [Please accept as an answer](http://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png), so others will benefit in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
var loadclass="<?php echo '.', $loadclass; ?>";
var load_address="<?php echo $load_address, '.php' ?>";
$(loadclass).load("dialogs/filter_group/",$(load_address) );
```

with

```
var loadclass="<?php echo '.' . $loadclass"; ?>";
var load_address="<?php echo $load_address . '.php'; ?>";
$(loadclass).load("dialogs/filter_group/" + load_address );
```

The string concatenatio sign is '.' in php and '+' in javascript, not ','

Simpler:

```
$("<?='.' . $loadclass ?>").load("dialogs/filter_group/<?= $load_address . '.php' ?>");
```

In both cases (with your initial values) results in:

```
$(".filtersin").load("dialogs/filter_group/recebimento-filter.php");
```